# Cakephp - trying to emulate a simple sql query involving join of 3 tables and 2 where conditions

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 Models

1. `MktingCampaign`
2. `Campaign`
3. `IvrNumber`

`MktingCampaign` hasMany `Campaign` and `Campaign` hasOne `IvrNumber`.

I am trying to emulate this query -

```
select * from mkting_campaign 
join campaign on mkting_campaign.id = campaign.mkting_campaign_id 
join ivr_numbers on campaign.id = ivr_numbers.campaign_id 
where campaign.status = 1 and ivr_numbers.status = 0;
```

What it does is It gets mkting_campaigns whose `campaigns.status = 1 and ivr_numbers.status = 0`.

I wrote this,

```
$this->MktingCampaign->find('all',array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Campaign' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Campaign.status' => 1), 
            'IvrNumber' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'IvrNumber.status' => 0
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Its returning all mkting_campaigns and populating the mkting_campaigns with campaign and ivrnumbers which are satisfying the above status conditions. But I want only the mkting_campaigns which are satisfying the above conditions (not all mkting_campaigns)

I have two solutions here

1. I can use joins instead. But is it a good practise ?
2. I have to implement some logic on result to filter unwanted `mkting_Campaigns` but isn't there a better way to modify query to get only desired results ?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `Containable` does not join `hasMany`. You can bind the `hasMany` as a `hasOne` for the conditions and leave the containable for the data.

before the query

$this->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array(....)));

The add to your query:

```
'contain' => array(
    'HasOneAliasFromAbove',
    ... other contains ....
),
'conditions' => array(
   'HasOneAliasFromAbove.field' => 'value'
)
```

You could also add the condition directly in the relation which would give you a join like

```
LEFT JOIN foo as Foo ON (... your conditions ...)
```

Or you could make it a `RIGHT JOIN` which will only fetch rows with the related data.

Comment: Is it a good practise ? Do I need to bindModel everytime I wanted to do a join even though I specified my assosciations in Models ?

Comment: bindModel is a way of creating associations on the fly. It is the same thing essentially. You could do it in the $hasOne property of the model too, although it would be pointless as you normally need some fk to join with

Comment: So, even if a Model 'hasMany' another model, just for query purposes, do I need to make it 'hasOne' ?

Comment: Here is more details on what is going on http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations

Comment: Thanks! problem solved but looks a bit wierd and roundabout solution. I still didnt get the point - Why should I give false relations to get my things done!

Comment: Cake will automatically create the ON(foo = bar) based on the foreign Keys. if you specify conditions cakes default will be merged with your conditions. If you make the fk false cake does not do anything and only the conditions specified will be used.